# Don't understand why Solve fails to find solution for my system of equations

Tags: equation-solving

I have one set of equations which `Solve` can handle, but when I give `Solve` second set (which I think is very similar to the first), it can't handle the second set — it returns an empty list.

This is the first set.

```
b = -2.8;
σ = {{a*b*x, 2*y}, {2*y, (a + c)*y}};
Solve[
  {0 == D[σ[[1, 1]], x] +  D[σ[[1, 2]], y], 
   0 == D[σ[[2, 1]], x] +  D[σ[[2, 2]], y]}, 
  {a, c}]`
```

[image]

This is the second set.

```
b = 1.9;
youngsMod = 70 * 1000000000;
ν = 1/3;
ϵ = {{a*b*x, 2*y}, {2*y, (a + c)*y}};
ϵp = {{ϵ[[1, 1]]}, {ϵ[[2, 1]]}, {2*ϵ[[2, 2]]}};
transformMatrix = 
  {{1/youngsMod, -ν/youngsMod, 0}, 
   {-ν/youngsMod, 1/youngsMod, 0}, 
   {0, 0, youngsMod/(2 (1 + ν))}};
σ = Inverse[transformMatrix].ϵp;
Solve[
  {0 == D[σ[[1, 1]], x] +  D[σ[[3, 1]], y], 
   0 == D[σ[[3, 1]], x] +  D[σ[[2, 1]], y]}, 
  {a, c}]
```

[image]

Why does `Solve` fail on the second set of equations, and is there anything I can do to get a solution.

Comment: As the `Solve` documentation states (look under "Details"!), `{}` means that no solutions exist. Do make sure to examine the equation you're solving in its final form though! If you do, you'll see that one of them evaluates to `False` immediately, and you'll see why.

Answer (score 1):

When writing code to perform a computation in an interpreted system like Mathematica, you should not ignore intermediate results, even though they are of no interest once the final result of the computation is obtained. These intermediate results often provide the information you need when some future step in the computation goes awry. The 2nd computation in your question is good example of the value of this practice.

In this case, `σ` is the culprit.

```
σ = Inverse[transformMatrix].ϵp
```

> ```
> {{1.49625*10^11 a x + 52500000000 y}, 
>    {4.9875*10^10 a x + 157500000000 y}, 
>    {0. + ((a + c) y)/13125000000}}
> ```

By inspection,`σ[[3, 1]]` is `0. + ((a + c) y)/13125000000` and `σ[[2, 1]]` is `4.9875*10^10 a x + 157500000000 y`.  That means `D[σ[[3, 1]], x]` is `0` and `D[σ[[2, 1]], y]` is `157500000000`. So your 2nd equation contains no variables and asserts the `0 == 0 + 157500000000`, which is false, and explains why `Solve` returns `{}`